# AngularJS ngrepeat - filter based on scope data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I am trying to create a dropdown menu using angular ng-repeat.
I have a jd object with a field called parent_id which indicates parent node under which this node should show up. Help I need is to create filter based on previous filtered data as shown in the markup

My markup code:

```
<div >
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" data-ng-controller= "MenuController" >
        <li data-ng-class="{'active':getClass('/customers')}"
            data-ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems | filter: { ParentId: '0' }" >
            <a href="#/customers"> {{ menuItem.Name }}    </a>
            **<ul>
                <li data-ng-repeat="menuItem1 in menuItems | filter: { ParentId: {{ menuItem1.ParentId }}  }">
                    {{ menuItem1.Name }}
                </li>
            </ul>**
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My Service:

```
app.service('menuService', function () {
this.getMenuItems = function () {
    return  menuItems;
};
var menuItems = [
    {
        id: 'ABCDFER1', Name: 'Apperal', ParentId: 0, description: 'Beautifull Apparels'
    },
    {
        id: 'ABCDFER2', Name: 'Electronics', ParentId: 0, description: 'Electronic bargains'
    },
    {
        id: 'ABCDFER3', Name: 'Home & Kitchen', ParentId: 0, description: 'For your kitchen'
    },
    {
        id: 'ABCDFER4', Name: 'Services', ParentId: 0, description: 'Services for you'
    },
    {
        id: 'ABCDFER5', Name: 'Men', ParentId: 'ABCDFER1', description: 'Men Apperal'
    },
    {
        id: 'ABCDFER6', Name: 'Women', ParentId: 'ABCDFER1', description: 'Women Apperal'
    }
];
```

My controller:

```
$scope.menuItems = menuService.getMenuItems();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you're trying to accomplish, I believe you want this:

```
<div >
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" data-ng-controller= "MenuController" >
        <li data-ng-class="{'active':getClass('/customers')}"
            data-ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems | filter: { ParentId: '0' }" >
            <a href="#/customers"> {{ menuItem.Name }} </a>
            <ul>
                <li data-ng-repeat="menuItem1 in menuItems | filter: { ParentId: menuItem.id }">
                    {{ menuItem1.Name }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Changes of note:

- You want to filter on the id of the parent item, not the parentId of
  the current item.
- You don't need {{ }} around the filter value, because this is interpreted as code, not a template.

Comment: I think it's {{}} in the filter was killing me. Will check and get back. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thanks McCrohan - works like charm :)
Any dropdown menu directive in Angular ?

Comment: Probably several. Check out Angular ui-bootstrap for one, though: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/